# Integer part of $e^x$

Tags: number-theory

Using wolfram alpha gives that $\lfloor e^{2015}\rfloor \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Is it possible to prove this by manual ?

Thank you.

Comment: How much time do you have? Anything wolfram does you can do manually. Are you sure Wolfram is correct? It might be using a bad approximation...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Not *even* wrong...

Comment: There might be some combinatorial problem related to $\lfloor e^n\rfloor$... [There is one for $\lfloor \frac{n!}e\rfloor$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), at least.

Comment: @barto $\lfloor \frac{n!}{e}+\frac{1}{2}\rfloor$, actually. Or $\left[\frac{n!}{e}\right]$, where $[x]$ is the [nearest integer function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_integer_function).

Comment: The same result, i.e. 1, is produced by Maple. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xl46wp1c686psih/floor.pdf?dl=0) is it.

Comment: When I enter `e^2015-floor(e^2015)`, it returns $0.\times 10^{862}$, which seems to indicate either that $e^{2015}$ is very very close to an integer, or we don't have a lot of significant digits here. You can get WA to dump enough digits, and the fractional part starts $0.5777...$. Trusting software to compute to $870$ digits all the time correctly is usually unwise. I realize WA is cool, and it is highly likely correct, but it is not wise to trust it unless there is documentation that says, "We will do $X$ computation using an ideal precision." @Zach466920

Comment: The answer to your specific question is Yes (though it might be very long and tedious work before you complete the task).

Comment: Given that Wolfram Alpha says the fractional part is more than 1/2, you can limit your computation to the first $n\approx 3\cdot 2015$ terms of the usual series for $e^z$. You only need to terms to about $8$ digits, and you can reduce each term to a real in $[0,4)$. Some clever simplification might make it possible to do by hand in a day.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Why only 8 digits?  Or did you mean 8 digits after the decimal point?  You're likely to need to compute hundreds of significant digits for the largest of the terms: if you're adding ~6000 terms, then you'd want each term to have an *absolute* error of at most 10**-5 (say) to have some hope of being able to determine the eventual floor unambiguously.

Comment: BTW, Python's `Decimal.exp` function confirms the answer of `1`.  The algorithm that function uses is documented to give correctly rounded results.

Comment: @MarkDickinson You can reduce the real numbers modulo $4$ for each term, so you get one digit left of the decimal, and eight after. So I guess, technically, that's nine digits.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Ah, I see what you're saying.  True: we only need to *keep* 8 or 9 digits for each term before adding, but we're still going to have to compute the hundreds of digits of each term prior to the reduction modulo 4.

Comment: Sure, to compute $\frac{2015^k}{k!}\pmod 4$ you have to do some complicated arithmetic. There might be a clever way to do so - each term is $\frac{2015}{k}$ times the previous, so at worst, it is inductive. @MarkDickinson

Comment: And I was wrong - you need more terms than $3\cdot 2015$ terms to get a good approximation. Closer to $2015\log 2015$, or more.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Term $5500$ is around $7.385\cdot 10^{-13}$, so $3\cdot 2015$ terms sounds like plenty to me.  (The sum of all terms past term $5500$ doesn't exceed $2\cdot 10^{-12}$.)